# can, could, may or might?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

I need to explain what  a time capsule is or how to make one. Should I say: "a time capsule can / could / may / might be any kind of box: a metal box, a wooden box or a cardboard box ..." I would use MIGHT because of the multiplicity of possible materials that can be used for this purpose.

Comment: None of those options is wrong. Personally, I would choose _can_ for instructions on making one - 'You can use any kind of box'.

Comment: *May* seems the least likely, but they have slightly different contexts. *Could* and *might* would be more applicable if you happened to find something to use, or were uncertain if you could have a time capsule, rather than if you deliberately chose something.